# Magento : I want to create custom url for my custom module

Tags: magento, custom-url

Currently I am using webkul extension for `multi vendor` site.
So the seller collection is available on :

> example.com/marketplace/seller/collection/sellerurl

Now I want to change this url to :

> example.com/sellerurl

I tried to use `custom router` but I wasn't able to achieve it to the mark.
Can someone help me with it??

Comment: You can learn on add product category they have URL Key. should be same the procedure to make the url like that.

Comment: Yes, It does work fine for category but I want to know the process for custom-module. I know the drill for category but its not working for custom modules.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we are the magento marketplace multi vendor module developer https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html This part is a feature of the module and you can change it from [seller panel](http://webkul.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/seller-url.png) As explained in the [user guide](http://webkul.com/blog/magento-multi-seller-marketplace/) . Still have any doubt please contact at our support center .

**PS - we are not self promoting our plugin or product , as user asked the questions specifically about our product that why i have added extension link with images and screenshot**

Comment: i ma using your extention but this url rewrite step not working in enterprise magento why

Comment: can you please guide

Comment: sure please email us at support@webkul.com and we will look in to it